# How to Call VC++ Dll from my windows phone application?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have to call VC++ dll in my windows phone project.

I trying using windows runtime component project as a bridge.

Windows Phone Project <-> Windows runtime component <-> vc++ project

is this right direction or i need to do it with other way....?

Comment: What’s the type of your dll, x86, x64 or ARM?

Comment: you can not use a x64 dll on Windows Phone, it should be a ARM dll.

Comment: Oke. So it is ok if i am use WIN32 dll. for same task? because i also have win32 dll.?

Comment: Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Unless you have the source and can rebuild for Phone ARM (not Desktop ARM) you are out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a DLL compiled for Intel x64 architecture. You cannot load that on Windows Phone which runs on ARM.